# R Error: scheme not supported in URL - However when I paste in the URL to website it works

Tags: r, url, download

I'm trying to bulk download sea surface temperature data using a script. When I run my code it gives me the error scheme not supported in URL, however, when I paste in the URL it works. Any ideas what going on?

```
#Bulk .nc downloader 
rm(list=ls())
datelist = seq(as.Date("2003-01-16"), as.Date("2019-11-16"), by="months")


len = length(datelist)
for(i in 1:len){
  date = gsub("-","", datelist[i])
  dl   = paste("C:/Documents/GIS_Data/SST/MODIS/SST_WestUS_025DegreesMonthly/SST_",datelist[i],".nc", sep="")
  url  = paste("https:/coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/erdMH1sstdmday.nc?sst[(",datelist[i],"T00:00:00Z):1:(",datelist[i],"T00:00:00Z)][(44.3125):1:(28.64583)][(-130.0208):1:(-114.3542)]", sep="")
  dat  = download.file(url=url, destfile=dl, mode = "w")
  download.file()
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in the URL that your browser automatically corrects - `https:/` instead of `https://`.

Comment: Thanks that helped with the accessing the website and downloading a singular file. Now I'm getting a new error and I have updated m `code`  Error in download.file() : 
  argument "destfile" is missing, with no default   - I looked at some other message boards and updated R and R studio but I still get the same error

Comment: No worries on the last comment. I was able to figure it out - I had some legacy code in there from its previous use. I needed to replace the last two lines with `code` download.file(url=url, destfile=dl, mode = "w")